# How do I programmatically list all the data types in a SQLite database?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Using C# with non-SQLite databases (such as SQL Server, Oracle, etc), you can loop through the DataTable returned from DbConnection.GetSchema("DataTypes") to look at all the supported data types of that database.

Unfortunately, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection does not support the GetSchema() method. So, how can I programmatically list all the supported data types in a SQLite database?

Comment: Why does it have to be programatically? https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @stuartd it's a requirement of the application

Comment: There's only 5 possible types,and that's counting null. Just stick their names in an array.

Answer (score 0):

In order to programatically determine all data types used in a particular SQLite database schema, you can leverage the `sqlite_master` table in conjunction with a pragma statement for each table.

In two steps:

1. Execute the query:

> ```
> select tbl_name from sqlite_master where type = 'table';
> ```

2. Iterate over each table name (tbl_name) returned from the query and
   run the query:

> pragma table_info(tbl_name);

Use the returned `type` column to build your unique list of date types used across the entire database.